# MVC passing Select Data from View to Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

```
    <select name="slt" id="slt">

        <option>Choose An Option</option>

        @if (Model != null)
        {

            foreach (var Users in Model)
            {

                <option> @Users.CustomerName</option>

            }

        }
    </select>
```

How do i pass this selected username to my MVC controller.I am just starting to learn C# pardon me

Controller:
 public ActionResult InsertRole()
{

```
        Users CustName = new Users();

        CustName.CustomerName = Request["slt"];

        string message = CustName.CustomerName;

        MessageBox.Show(message);

        return View();

    }
```

Comment: Can you post what you already tried ?

Comment: i did a button to trigger this InsertRole action

Comment: did you try `var x = Request.QueryString["slt"];` ?